# How do I fix this 'Partial Upgrade' problem (related to CUDA and Tensorflow)?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, upgrade, cuda

My Lubuntu system has recently started complaining that it cannot update software and is offering a Partial Upgrade - which I understand is bad news.

I suspect it is related to my Tensorflow installation (most of my problems are, and I fear changing it in any way !).

`nvcc --version` reports release 10.1, V10.1.243

`nvidia-smi` reports Driver Version: 440.64.00 CUDA Version: 10.2

cuDNN is version 7.6

Tensorflow is version 1.14.0

It appears that the update wants to remove the cuda and nvidia driver packages (I have appended the output from dist-upgrade).  Please can someone explain what the root of the problem is here, and what I can do to move on (hopefully without totally destroying my working tensorflow installation).

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-1 cuda-cufft-10-1 cuda-cufft-dev-10-1
  cuda-cuobjdump-10-1 cuda-cupti-10-1 cuda-curand-10-1 cuda-curand-dev-10-1
  cuda-cusolver-10-1 cuda-cusolver-dev-10-1 cuda-cusparse-10-1 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-1
  cuda-documentation-10-1 cuda-gdb-10-1 cuda-gpu-library-advisor-10-1
  cuda-libraries-10-1 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 cuda-memcheck-10-1 cuda-misc-headers-10-1
  cuda-npp-10-1 cuda-npp-dev-10-1 cuda-nsight-10-1 cuda-nsight-compute-10-1
  cuda-nsight-systems-10-1 cuda-nvcc-10-1 cuda-nvdisasm-10-1 cuda-nvgraph-10-1
  cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-10-1 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-1 cuda-nvml-dev-10-1
  cuda-nvprof-10-1 cuda-nvprune-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-10-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-1 cuda-nvtx-10-1
  cuda-nvvp-10-1 cuda-samples-10-1 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-1 cuda-toolkit-10-1
  cuda-tools-10-1 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-common-440
  libnvidia-fbc1-440 libxnvctrl0 linux-headers-4.15.0-96 linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-96-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-96-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-96-generic nsight-compute-2019.5.0 nsight-systems-2019.5.2
  nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings python-apt python-bs4 python-html5lib python-lxml python-webencodings
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  cuda-10-1 cuda-demo-suite-10-1 cuda-drivers cuda-runtime-10-1 libnvidia-decode-440
  libnvidia-encode-440 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-ifr1-440 nvidia-dkms-440
  nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-utils-440
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-4.15.0-106 linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-106-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-106-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-106-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptdaemon aptdaemon-data ca-certificates chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra firefox
  firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer google-chrome-stable intel-microcode
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjson-c-dev libjson-c3 libnautilus-extension1a
  libnetplan0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
  libpulsedsp libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.1 libsystemd0
  libudev1 libxnvctrl0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic netplan.io nodejs nplan nvidia-modprobe
  nvidia-settings openssl pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils
  python-apt python-apt-common python-rosdistro python-rosdistro-modules python3-apport
  python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-problem-report
  python3-software-properties ros-melodic-actionlib ros-melodic-actionlib-msgs
  ros-melodic-actionlib-tutorials ros-melodic-angles ros-melodic-bond
  ros-melodic-bond-core ros-melodic-bondcpp ros-melodic-bondpy
  ros-melodic-camera-calibration ros-melodic-camera-calibration-parsers
  ros-melodic-camera-info-manager ros-melodic-catkin ros-melodic-class-loader
  ros-melodic-cmake-modules ros-melodic-common-msgs ros-melodic-common-tutorials
  ros-melodic-compressed-depth-image-transport ros-melodic-compressed-image-transport
  ros-melodic-control-msgs ros-melodic-control-toolbox ros-melodic-controller-interface
  ros-melodic-controller-manager ros-melodic-controller-manager-msgs
  ros-melodic-cpp-common ros-melodic-cv-bridge ros-melodic-depth-image-proc
  ros-melodic-desktop ros-melodic-desktop-full ros-melodic-diagnostic-aggregator
  ros-melodic-diagnostic-analysis ros-melodic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics
  ros-melodic-diagnostic-msgs ros-melodic-diagnostic-updater ros-melodic-diagnostics
  ros-melodic-diff-drive-controller ros-melodic-dynamic-reconfigure
  ros-melodic-eigen-conversions ros-melodic-executive-smach ros-melodic-filters
  ros-melodic-forward-command-controller ros-melodic-gazebo-dev ros-melodic-gazebo-msgs
  ros-melodic-gazebo-plugins ros-melodic-gazebo-ros ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control
  ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-melodic-gencpp ros-melodic-geneus ros-melodic-genlisp
  ros-melodic-genmsg ros-melodic-gennodejs ros-melodic-genpy ros-melodic-geometry
  ros-melodic-geometry-msgs ros-melodic-geometry-tutorials ros-melodic-gl-dependency
  ros-melodic-hardware-interface ros-melodic-image-common ros-melodic-image-geometry
  ros-melodic-image-pipeline ros-melodic-image-proc ros-melodic-image-publisher
  ros-melodic-image-rotate ros-melodic-image-transport
  ros-melodic-image-transport-plugins ros-melodic-image-view
  ros-melodic-interactive-marker-tutorials ros-melodic-interactive-markers
  ros-melodic-joint-limits-interface ros-melodic-joint-state-controller
  ros-melodic-joint-state-publisher ros-melodic-kdl-conversions ros-melodic-kdl-parser
  ros-melodic-kdl-parser-py ros-melodic-laser-assembler ros-melodic-laser-filters
  ros-melodic-laser-geometry ros-melodic-laser-pipeline ros-melodic-librviz-tutorial
  ros-melodic-libuvc ros-melodic-libuvc-camera ros-melodic-map-msgs
  ros-melodic-media-export ros-melodic-message-filters ros-melodic-message-generation
  ros-melodic-message-runtime ros-melodic-mk ros-melodic-nav-msgs ros-melodic-nodelet
  ros-melodic-nodelet-core ros-melodic-nodelet-topic-tools
  ros-melodic-nodelet-tutorial-math ros-melodic-orocos-kdl ros-melodic-pcl-conversions
  ros-melodic-pcl-msgs ros-melodic-pcl-ros ros-melodic-perception
  ros-melodic-perception-pcl ros-melodic-pluginlib ros-melodic-pluginlib-tutorials
  ros-melodic-polled-camera ros-melodic-position-controllers
  ros-melodic-python-orocos-kdl ros-melodic-python-qt-binding ros-melodic-qt-dotgraph
  ros-melodic-qt-gui ros-melodic-qt-gui-cpp ros-melodic-qt-gui-py-common
  ros-melodic-qwt-dependency ros-melodic-realtime-tools ros-melodic-resource-retriever
  ros-melodic-robot ros-melodic-robot-state-publisher ros-melodic-ros
  ros-melodic-ros-base ros-melodic-ros-comm ros-melodic-ros-core
  ros-melodic-ros-environment ros-melodic-ros-tutorials ros-melodic-rosbag
  ros-melodic-rosbag-migration-rule ros-melodic-rosbag-storage ros-melodic-rosbash
  ros-melodic-rosboost-cfg ros-melodic-rosbuild ros-melodic-rosclean
  ros-melodic-rosconsole ros-melodic-rosconsole-bridge ros-melodic-roscpp
  ros-melodic-roscpp-core ros-melodic-roscpp-serialization ros-melodic-roscpp-traits
  ros-melodic-roscpp-tutorials ros-melodic-roscreate ros-melodic-rosgraph
  ros-melodic-rosgraph-msgs ros-melodic-roslang ros-melodic-roslaunch ros-melodic-roslib
  ros-melodic-roslint ros-melodic-roslisp ros-melodic-roslz4 ros-melodic-rosmake
  ros-melodic-rosmaster ros-melodic-rosmsg ros-melodic-rosnode ros-melodic-rosout
  ros-melodic-rospack ros-melodic-rosparam ros-melodic-rospy ros-melodic-rospy-tutorials
  ros-melodic-rosservice ros-melodic-rostest ros-melodic-rostime ros-melodic-rostopic
  ros-melodic-rosunit ros-melodic-roswtf ros-melodic-rqt-action ros-melodic-rqt-bag
  ros-melodic-rqt-bag-plugins ros-melodic-rqt-common-plugins ros-melodic-rqt-console
  ros-melodic-rqt-dep ros-melodic-rqt-graph ros-melodic-rqt-gui ros-melodic-rqt-gui-cpp
  ros-melodic-rqt-gui-py ros-melodic-rqt-image-view ros-melodic-rqt-launch
  ros-melodic-rqt-logger-level ros-melodic-rqt-moveit ros-melodic-rqt-msg
  ros-melodic-rqt-nav-view ros-melodic-rqt-plot ros-melodic-rqt-pose-view
  ros-melodic-rqt-publisher ros-melodic-rqt-py-common ros-melodic-rqt-py-console
  ros-melodic-rqt-reconfigure ros-melodic-rqt-robot-dashboard
  ros-melodic-rqt-robot-monitor ros-melodic-rqt-robot-plugins
  ros-melodic-rqt-robot-steering ros-melodic-rqt-runtime-monitor ros-melodic-rqt-rviz
  ros-melodic-rqt-service-caller ros-melodic-rqt-shell ros-melodic-rqt-srv
  ros-melodic-rqt-tf-tree ros-melodic-rqt-top ros-melodic-rqt-topic ros-melodic-rqt-web
  ros-melodic-rviz ros-melodic-rviz-plugin-tutorials ros-melodic-rviz-python-tutorial
  ros-melodic-self-test ros-melodic-sensor-msgs ros-melodic-shape-msgs
  ros-melodic-simulators ros-melodic-smach ros-melodic-smach-msgs ros-melodic-smach-ros
  ros-melodic-smclib ros-melodic-stage ros-melodic-stage-ros ros-melodic-std-msgs
  ros-melodic-std-srvs ros-melodic-stereo-image-proc ros-melodic-stereo-msgs
  ros-melodic-tf ros-melodic-tf-conversions ros-melodic-tf2 ros-melodic-tf2-eigen
  ros-melodic-tf2-geometry-msgs ros-melodic-tf2-kdl ros-melodic-tf2-msgs
  ros-melodic-tf2-py ros-melodic-tf2-ros ros-melodic-theora-image-transport
  ros-melodic-topic-tools ros-melodic-trajectory-msgs ros-melodic-transmission-interface
  ros-melodic-turtle-actionlib ros-melodic-turtle-tf ros-melodic-turtle-tf2
  ros-melodic-turtlesim ros-melodic-urdf ros-melodic-urdf-parser-plugin
  ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial ros-melodic-urdf-tutorial ros-melodic-urdfdom-py
  ros-melodic-usb-cam ros-melodic-vision-opencv
  ros-melodic-visualization-marker-tutorials ros-melodic-visualization-msgs
  ros-melodic-visualization-tutorials ros-melodic-viz ros-melodic-webkit-dependency
  ros-melodic-xacro ros-melodic-xmlrpcpp software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk steam-launcher systemd systemd-coredump systemd-sysv
  teamviewer udev xserver-common xserver-xorg-core
302 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 12 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Comment: Not really bad news. Just follow the steps outlined for a partial upgrade and all will be well. Maybe a bit disconcerting but it does work.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you haven't run upgrades in a long time. For some reason it thinks `cuda` was installed as a requirement for something that is no longer there. I personally would not proceed with the partial upgrade as suggested in the other comment.  I  would try to mark `cuda` and the nvidia drivers as manually installed so that it does not want to remove them.

Comment: @Organic Marble Your suggestion makes sense, but why does it appear that I have not run updates for some time ?  My system always updates automatically on a regular basis.

Comment: for example, the last time I got a pulseaudio update was a month ago. (Ok, maybe 2 weeks ago)

Answer (score 0):

Careful, the CUDA packages Nvidia supplied depend upon an obsolete Nvidia driver, probably 418.  When you re-installed the 440 drivers, the 418 got removed and all dependencies got marked for removal -- that's all the cuda files.    I'd immediately back-up the /usr/local/cuda-10.1 dir, which is an autoremove from disappearing.
For an original CUDA install of the Nvidia supplied release (not the older one supplied in the standard repos), I'd suggest avoiding the package manager entirely by just unpacking the deb file (and the content deb files), not installing anything.
For your situation (just like what I went through), I backed up the /usr/local/cuda-10.1 directory, ran the autoremove (which deleted the ...cuda-10.1), and restored the backed up files.   Look at

```
dpkg -l |grep cuda
```

and individually purge the cuda packages not in the "ii" state (all of them but 3).  I am left with nvidia-cuda-dev, libcdart10.1, and cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.243-418.87.00.  No more package manager complaints, and kernel updates will get the new Nvidia driver build automatically, as they should.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response.  I am mustering the emotional strength to try your method !